# HTTP Status code for indicating NON FATAL Server Error

Tags: php, apache, rest, http

I am in the process of building an API. I am using MVC architecture, my own mini-framework written in PHP.

This is API is RESTful but also provides a simultaneous real-time channel through Web Sockets using NodeJS. So, technically, some of the services are accessible via standard REST Interface and rest of the continuous state full flow is accessible via Web Sockets.

Because of this, it is very essential that I use HTTP error codes for a whole lot of fine grained scenarios.

Now, my question is pretty simple, **what should be the HTTP Status Code indicating a Server Error which is *non-fatal*?**

`501` is for Server Internal Error but here I am looking for a scenario where *some part* of the request couldn't be fulfilled.

Appreciate your help.

**A little more clarification about the actual scenario**

The request is successfully handled by the server, but this scenario arises when *after* completion of the request, the server cannot update the log. Thus it is a partial fulfillment.

Comment: I think your scenario is too specific to be given its own error code, so you can make your own error code and use that on this project? In the way that in the fullness of time when a valid error code is established that you can update your own code to reflect this?

Comment: That's what I did. But alas! I was trying hard to make it as compliant as possible and also intuitive for the consumers :(
I went with 522 al al Twitter 520's

Comment: All the end user wants is a notice of explanation, I think you can do this with custom headers? I know it's not absolutely within line but there doesn't appear to be anything established that fits what you're looking for, yet. Perhaps if you can find a similar situation (contrived or not) and then run that server past redbot.org and see how redbot.org handles it? Just an idea..

Comment: how do you want to use the header that you put out in this situation?

Comment: As an example, say user logged in and it could not be updated on the log server (which is a different server). Technically, it should be a 200 OK as the primary request was handled, but the failure of the non-essential action also has consequences. Thus, I am returning a 522 with OPTIONS in the header advising a GET URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, thinking about it, it seems to be that you're defining two situations in one stroke -

> The request is successfully handled by the server, but this scenario arises when after completion of the request, the server cannot update the log. Thus it is a partial fulfillment.

This actually appears to come across as two separate things:

The request is successfully handled, part 1, so that's a header 200 (lets say), but then if the log update is not completed that (*and only that*) is then an error 5xx. If you can establish *why* the log is not written and then return a specific *5xx* error for that specific reason.

If you want to only return a single header then even if the request is successfully handled, if the log is not updated correctly then the request is not actually handled successfully and a 5xx header should be returned as a 5xx header would take precedent over a 2xx header. If you're using the header for your own redirection then you can use a customer header because you know how you can handle that.

Comment: Great minds think alike :) That's exactly what I put in the comment.

Comment: awesome :) . HTTP Headers are very singular.